# Relationship between crystalline cohomology and crystalline representation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

I know some basics about crystalline cohomology and very little about crystalline representation. The two names suggest there should be some natural connections between them, but I was unable to find any in the literature. So is there any significant connection between crystalline cohomology and crystalline representations? For example, do the crystalline cohomology groups of a smooth projective variety give crystalline representations?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is a relationship between them. Comparing them literally makes no sense, as there is a type error. The crystalline cohomology produces a filtered $F$-(iso)crystal, but a crystalline representation is a type of Galois representation.

That said, the naming isn't too far off. Namely, Fontaine developed these notions well and, in particular, developed a functor

$$D_\mathrm{crys}\colon \mathbf{Rep}^\mathrm{crys}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K))\to F\text{-}\mathbf{FIsoc}(K),$$

where $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ which (just for simplicity) we ,the source is the category of crystalline representations, and the target the category of filtered $F$-isocrystals.

Let us denote by $k$ the residue field of $K$. Fontaine then conjectured the following known as *Fontaine's $C_\mathrm{crys}$ conjecture*, and proven by Faltings.

> **Theorem (Faltings):** Let $X\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ be a smooth proper scheme. Then, for each $i\geqslant 0$ the Galois representation $H^i_\mathrm{et}(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is crystalline, and $$D_\mathrm{crys}(H^i_\mathrm{et}(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_p))=H^i_\mathrm{crys}(X_{k}/W(k))\left[\tfrac{1}{p}\right].$$

In essence, one should think about crystalline representations over $K$ as being those which 'admit integral models' over $\mathcal{O}_K$ (something that can be made essentially precise using Bhatt--Scholze's recent theory of *prismatic $F$-crystals*), and then $D_\mathrm{crys}$ is something like 'taking the special fiber' of this model.

(NB: this is only partially true -- taking the special fiber is more like giving the underlying $F$-isocrystals, and forgetting filtration which depends on the actual formal deformation, but let's ignore this point here)

Thus, in some sense $D_\mathrm{crys}$ allows you to 'interpolate' between characteristic $0$ objects and characteristic $p$ objects (in a sort of 'motivic sense'), at least when this is possible -- at least when the representation is crystalline. The naming then makes sense given Fontaine's conjecture/Faltings's theorem, which says that under this sort of 'spreading out' $\mathbb{Q}_p\leadsto\mathbb{F}_p$, etale cohomology gets matched with crystalline cohomology which, from a motivic perspective, makes sense.